# Loop through a list of words/phrases, match with database table rows

Tags: c#, mysql, regex, datagridview

I have a list of words/phrases in a .txt (each word/phrase in new line), I want to loop through each word/phrase and check whether these words/phrases appear in 6th column of the comments table. I cannot work it out the below code, nothing appear in my datagridview despite having the matched "keywords", can anyone review/correct my code? Thank you.

```
private void button_Search1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable flaggedcomments = new DataTable("flaggedcomments");
    using (MySqlConnection sqlConn = new MySqlConnection(strProvider))
    {
        using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT Comment_ID, Comments_Date, Comments_Time, Author, Title, Comments_Comment FROM comments ORDER BY Comments_Date ASC, Comments_Time ASC", sqlConn))
        {
            da.Fill(flaggedcomments);
        }
    }
    string[] words = File.ReadAllLines(sourceDirTemp + "a_list_of_words_and_phrases.txt");
    foreach (DataRow da in flaggedcomments.Rows)
    {
        string itemComments = da[5].ToString();
        if (words.Any(wordOrPhrase => Regex.IsMatch(itemComments, @"\b" + Regex.Escape(wordOrPhrase) + @"\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)))
        {
            dataGridView_flaggedComments.Rows.Add(da);
            string itemTitle = da[4].ToString();
            string itemDate = da[1].ToString().Replace(" 12:00:00 AM", "");
            string itemTime = da[2].ToString();
            string itemAuthor = da[3].ToString();
            string itemCommentID = da[0].ToString();

            richTextBox_flaggedComments.AppendText("Date: " + itemDate + "\nTime: " + itemTime + "\nCommenter: " + itemAuthor + "\nTitle: " + itemTitle + "\nDescription: " + itemComments + "\nComment ID: " + itemCommentID + "\n\n--------\n\n");
        }
    }
}
```

I thought the `Rows.Add(da)` line would work, but when I clicked the button, it gives me error saying no row can be added to a datagridview control that does not have columns.

Sample "Comments_Comment" is e.g.

> Aberdeen Asset Management will release a trading update for the two months to 28 February following regulatory approval for its acquisition of Scottish Widows Investment Partnership.Analysts' expectations: 'For the two months we expect assets under management of £188 billion down 3 per cent from its first quarter.

Comment: Can you give an example of what a value from "Comments_Comment" looks like?

Comment: @MikeHixson I have edited my code from `dataGridView_flaggedComments.DataSource = da;` to `dataGridView_flaggedComments.Rows.Add(da);`. I think it will work, but when I clicked the button, it gives me error saying `no row can be added to a datagridview control that does not have columns`.

Comment: @MikeHixson sample comment is e.g. `Aberdeen Asset Management will release a trading update for the two months to 28 February following regulatory approval for its acquisition of Scottish Widows Investment Partnership.Analysts' expectations: 'For the two months we expect assets under management of &#163;188 billion down 3 per cent from its first quarter.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using databinding, instead of trying to add rows to the gridview. You can replace the `foreach` in your code with this:

```
var query = flaggedcomments.AsEnumerable().Where(r =>
    words.Any(wordOrPhrase => Regex.IsMatch(r.Field<string>("Comments_Comment"), @"\b" + Regex.Escape(wordOrPhrase) + @"\b",
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)));

dataGridView_flaggedComments.DataSource = query.AsDataView();
```

You will need to have a reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll in your visual studio project for this work.

Comment: Hi Mike, this works like a charm! :) But the reason I was using `foreach` is because apart from displaying the results in a DGV, I am also going to write out the matched comments in a richtextbox. I edited my original code (to show you the original `append text` code), can you have a look?

Comment: Hi again Mike, kindly ignore my previous question. I believe I've successfully written the result into richtextbox, after your code. I've accepted your answer, thank you very much! :)